# Applying style using css selectors not working

Tags: css, for-loop, css-selectors

I'm using a loop to display my list.

```
<span v-for="freefeature in freefeatures" v-bind:key="freefeature">
   <i class="fa fa-check-circle free-icons"></i>
   <p>{{freefeature}}</p>
 </span>
```

**I want the first i (icon) to be of orange color and rest to be of grey color.**

I'm using this loop at multiple places without the free-icons class on i where all the icons need to be orange only at this place they need to be grey except for the first one hence the class "free-icons"

**What I've tried:**

```
 span i {
     color: orange; }

    span:nth-child(n+2) i.free-icons {
     color: #333;
}
```

Just to check even first-child selector or any other css selector in that case doesn't work. What I might be doing wrong?

Comment: when v-for is applied to span, the span will be repeated. So, we should select through a wrapper element. That is safe. Check my answer.

Comment: @StringSet please check what this loop of your's give you as rendered DOM set on the page, first and then write your CSS accordingly. As you said you're using this loop set at multiple places on your page but `class` `free-icons` is found only in this specific case, then do `color: orange` on all i's and then override the same with `color: gray` if `free-icons` `class` is there except for the first child in the relevant rendered DOM set. I think this would do the trick for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, use `nth-child(1)` or `first-child` to get first `i` , change your css logic, make first one `orange` and other `gray`

```css
span i {
  color: #333;
}

span i.free-icons:first-child {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<span v-for="freefeature in freefeatures" v-bind:key="freefeature">
   <i class="fa fa-check-circle free-icons">X</i>
   <p>{{freefeature}}</p>
   
   <i class="fa fa-check-circle free-icons">X</i>
   <p>{{freefeature}}</p>
   
   <i class="fa fa-check-circle free-icons">X</i>
   <p>{{freefeature}}</p>
 </span>
```

**Update:** alternate logic is using `:not`, exclude first child like this:

```css
span i.free-icons:not(:first-child) {
  color: #333;
}

span i {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<span v-for="freefeature in freefeatures" v-bind:key="freefeature">
   <i class="fa fa-check-circle free-icons">X</i>
   <p>{{freefeature}}</p>
   
   <i class="fa fa-check-circle free-icons">X</i>
   <p>{{freefeature}}</p>
   
   <i class="fa fa-check-circle free-icons">X</i>
   <p>{{freefeature}}</p>
 </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to have a wrapper element and then select the span through it

```css
span i {
  color: #333;
}

.wrapper span:first-child i.free-icons {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha256-+N4/V/SbAFiW1MPBCXnfnP9QSN3+Keu+NlB+0ev/YKQ=" crossorigin="anonymous" />


<div class="wrapper">
  <span>
     <i class="far fa-check-circle free-icons"></i>
     <p>Feature1</p>
   </span>

  <span>
     <i class="far fa-check-circle free-icons"></i>
     <p>Feature2</p>
   </span>


  <span>
     <i class="far fa-check-circle free-icons"></i>
     <p>Feature3</p>
   </span>


  <span>
     <i class="far fa-check-circle free-icons"></i>
     <p>Feature4</p>
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: `v-for` loop all data inside `span` not `span`, so `span` is a wrapper here. It's `vue.js` thing!